# Setvalues() from one spreadsheet to another not working

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to copy various cells from one spreadsheet and pasting them to another spreadseet. I have debugged the script multiple times and there are no bugs, but it is still not setting the values in the sheet.

```
function Pegarfechas(){

  var ficha = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('FICHA');
  var hojafechas = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1rCFTJuBoWgPgJ_9PV13VIApGYn8pSFa4S6VYAx5tOmU").getSheetByName('Fechas');
  var codigo=ficha.getRange("H2").getValue();
  var color =ficha.getRange("R2").getValue();
  var Sku = codigo + color;
  var fechas = ficha.getRange("D24:P24").getValues();
 // I defined the variables for better understanding      
  var startRow = hojafechas.getLastRow()+1; 
  var startColumn = 1
  hojafechas.getRange(startRow, startColumn).setValues[Sku, fechas];
};
```

I think the problem is at "hojafechas.getRange(startRow, startColumn).setValues[Sku,fechas];" but I have also tried to set the values separately and it still did not work. Does anybody know what could be happening and how I could fix it?
I want to paste Sku in Column 1 in the other spreadsheet and "fechas" in the Columns right next to it.
Thank you so much in advance :)

[image: How i want it to look :)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try:

```
function Pegarfechas(){

  const ficha = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('FICHA');
  const hojafechas = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1rCFTJuBoWgPgJ_9PV13VIApGYn8pSFa4S6VYAx5tOmU").getSheetByName('Fechas');
  const codigo = ficha.getRange("H2").getValue();
  const color = ficha.getRange("R2").getValue();
  const Sku = codigo + color;
  const fechas = ficha.getRange("D24:P24").getValues().flat();

  const values = [[Sku, ...fechas]];

  hojafechas.getRange(1, 1, 1, values[0].length).setValues(values);

};
```

### Explained:

```
// Creates a 'row' of data, beginning with `Sku` and `fechas`'s values spread out.
const values = [[Sku, ...fechas]];

// Using the dimensions of the `values` array, set the values in the sheet.
hojafechas.getRange(1, 1, 1, values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

- [Range.setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [Functions - JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)

Comment: what do you mean? would you mind writing the whole line? Sorry, I tried a couple of times and it didn't work

Comment: @VivianRoberts Updated. Functions (or 'Methods' in this case) require parenthesis to pass data. If this still isn't working for some reason, please post any errors you may be receiving!

Comment: thank you so much! i didn't know. I tried it and got "Exception: The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues.", what should I do now?

Comment: We have progress! I've updated my post one more time, this should solve it for you.

Comment: sorry! changed the getvalue to getdisplay value but I'm still getting the same :(

Comment: no worries! I added a picture so you can see how it should look, Sku should be in column A and fechas in B to M :)

Comment: Ba-boom! Try the updated code

Comment: okay there is progress! it is now working but it's only setting the values in column A and B

Comment: @VivianRoberts Okay, this is it! Get ready!  `const fechas = ficha.getRange("D24:P24").getValues().flat();`

Comment: it's working!! thank you so much!!!

Comment: Wahoo! Sorry for the trouble. Let me know if you have any further questions